# Windows batch file to strip the ampersands from the xml files

Tags: xml, batch-file

I am currently working on try to strip out all ampersands within an xml file. However, I am having some difficulty in achieving this due to being new to writing windows batch files.

If anyone could assign me with this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a robust batch solution using a native scripting tool.
It strips all `&` characters from the `file.xml`

```
type "file.xml"|repl "&" "" L >"newfile.xml"
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

Answer (score 1):

This is a vbs file. It searches and replaces using regular expressions. It is NOT line based butwhole file.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ReportErrors "Creating Shell.App"
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ReportErrors "Creating Wscript.Shell"
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
ReportErrors "Creating Wscript.Arg"
Set regEx = New RegExp
ReportErrors "Creating RegEx"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ReportErrors "Creating FSO"

If objArgs.Count = 0 then
        MsgBox "No parameters", 16, "ReplaceRegExp"
        ReportErrors "Help"
ElseIf objArgs.Count = 1 then
        MsgBox "Only one parameter", 16, "ReplaceRegExp"
        ReportErrors "Help"
ElseIf objArgs.Count = 2 then
        Set srcfile = fso.GetFile(objArgs(0))
        ReportErrors "srcFile"
        If err.number = 0 then Set TS = srcFile.OpenAsTextStream(1, 0)
        If err.number <> 0 then
            Msgbox err.description & " " & srcFile.path, 48, "Search" 
            err.clear
        else
            ReportErrors "TS" & "     " & srcFile.path
            Src=ts.readall
            If err.number = 62 then
                err.clear
            else
                ReportErrors "ReadTS" & "     " & srcFile.path
                regEx.Pattern = objArgs(1) 
                regEx.IgnoreCase = True
                regEx.Global = True
                If regEx.Test(Src) = True then
                    Msgbox "Found in " & srcfile.path, 64, "Search" 
                End If
            End If
        End If
        ReportErrors "Check OK" & "     " & srcFile.path

Elseif objArgs.count = 3 then
        Set srcfile = fso.GetFile(objArgs(0))
        ReportErrors "srcFile"
        If err.number = 0 then Set TS = srcFile.OpenAsTextStream(1, 0)
        If err.number <> 0 then
            Msgbox err.description & " " & srcFile.path, 48, "Search" 
            err.clear
        else
            ReportErrors "TS" & "     " & srcFile.path
            Src=ts.readall
            If err.number = 62 then
                err.clear
            else
                ReportErrors "ReadTS" & "     " & srcFile.path
                regEx.Pattern = objArgs(1) 
                regEx.IgnoreCase = True
                regEx.Global = True
                NewSrc= regEx.Replace(Src, objArgs(2)) 
                If NewSrc<>Src then
                    Msgbox "Replacement made in " & srcfile.path, 64, "Serenity's Search" 
                    TS.close
                    Set TS = srcFile.OpenAsTextStream(2, 0)
                    ts.write newsrc
                    ReportErrors "Writing file"
                End If
            End If
        End If
        ReportErrors "Check OK" & "     " & srcFile.path


Else
        MsgBox "Too many parameters", 16, "ReplaceRegExp"
        ReportErrors "Help"

ReportErrors "All Others"
End If

Sub ReportErrors(strModuleName)
    If err.number<>0 then Msgbox "An unexpected error occurred. This dialog provides details on the error." & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "Error Details " & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "Script Name" & vbTab & Wscript.ScriptFullName & vbCRLF & "Module" & vbtab & vbTab & strModuleName & vbCRLF & "Error Number" & vbTab & err.number & vbCRLF & "Description" & vbTab & err.description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Something unexpected"
    Err.clear
End Sub
```

In a command prompt. Full path specified and ampersand (your search string) escaped.

```
"C:\path\ReplaceRegExp.vbs" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Folder Property List.txt" "^&" ""
```

Note it was designed to be used in Start - Run. Run once and it installs.

```
ReplaceRegExp.vbs "%userprofile%\Desktop\Folder Property List.txt" "&" ""
```

This is the pattern docs.

Settings
Special characters and sequences are used in writing patterns for regular expressions. The following table describes and gives an example of the characters and sequences that can be used.

Character  Description
\ 
 Marks the next character as either a special character or a literal. For example, "n" matches the character "n". "\n" matches a newline character. The sequence "\" matches "\" and "(" matches "(".

^ 
 Matches the beginning of input.

$ 
 Matches the end of input.

- Matches the preceding character zero or more times. For example, "zo*" matches either "z" or "zoo".
- Matches the preceding character one or more times. For example, "zo+" matches "zoo" but not "z".

? 
 Matches the preceding character zero or one time. For example, "a?ve?" matches the "ve" in "never".

.
 Matches any single character except a newline character.

(pattern)
 Matches pattern and remembers the match. The matched substring can be retrieved from the resulting Matches collection, using Item [0]...[n]. To match parentheses characters ( ), use "(" or ")".

x|y
 Matches either x or y. For example, "z|wood" matches "z" or "wood". "(z|w)oo" matches "zoo" or "wood".

{n}
 n is a nonnegative integer. Matches exactly n times. For example, "o{2}" does not match the "o" in "Bob," but matches the first two o's in "foooood".

{n,} 
 n is a nonnegative integer. Matches at least n times. For example, "o{2,}" does not match the "o" in "Bob" and matches all the o's in "foooood." "o{1,}" is equivalent to "o+". "o{0,}" is equivalent to "o*".

{ n , m } 
 m and n are nonnegative integers. Matches at least n and at most m times. For example, "o{1,3}" matches the first three o's in "fooooood." "o{0,1}" is equivalent to "o?".

[ xyz ] 
 A character set. Matches any one of the enclosed characters. For example, "[abc]" matches the "a" in "plain".

[^ xyz ] 
 A negative character set. Matches any character not enclosed. For example, "[^abc]" matches the "p" in "plain".

[ a-z ] 
 A range of characters. Matches any character in the specified range. For example, "[a-z]" matches any lowercase alphabetic character in the range "a" through "z".

[^ m-z ] 
 A negative range characters. Matches any character not in the specified range. For example, "[m-z]" matches any character not in the range "m" through "z".

\b 
 Matches a word boundary, that is, the position between a word and a space. For example, "er\b" matches the "er" in "never" but not the "er" in "verb".

\B 
 Matches a non-word boundary. "ea*r\B" matches the "ear" in "never early".

\d 
 Matches a digit character. Equivalent to [0-9].

\D 
 Matches a non-digit character. Equivalent to [^0-9].

\f 
 Matches a form-feed character.

\n 
 Matches a newline character.

\r 
 Matches a carriage return character.

\s 
 Matches any white space including space, tab, form-feed, etc. Equivalent to "[ \f\n\r\t\v]".

\S 
 Matches any nonwhite space character. Equivalent to "[^ \f\n\r\t\v]".

\t 
 Matches a tab character.

\v 
 Matches a vertical tab character.

\w 
 Matches any word character including underscore. Equivalent to "[A-Za-z0-9_]".

\W 
 Matches any non-word character. Equivalent to "[^A-Za-z0-9_]".

\num 
 Matches num, where num is a positive integer. A reference back to remembered matches. For example, "(.)\1" matches two consecutive identical characters.

\ n 
 Matches n, where n is an octal escape value. Octal escape values must be 1, 2, or 3 digits long. For example, "\11" and "\011" both match a tab character. "\0011" is the equivalent of "\001" & "1". Octal escape values must not exceed 256. If they do, only the first two digits comprise the expression. Allows ASCII codes to be used in regular expressions.

\xn
 Matches n, where n is a hexadecimal escape value. Hexadecimal escape values must be exactly two digits long. For example, "\x41" matches "A". "\x041" is equivalent to "\x04" & "1". Allows ASCII codes to be used in regular expressions.